# What's the best/fastest way to find the number of tabs to start a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, optimization

I want to find the number of tabs at the beginning of a string (and of course I want it to be fast running code ;) ). This is my idea, but not sure if this is the best/fastest choice:

```
//The regular expression
var findBegTabs = /(^\t+)/g;

//This string has 3 tabs and 2 spaces: "<tab><tab><space>something<space><tab>"
var str = "      something  ";

//Look for the tabs at the beginning
var match = reg.exec( str );

//We found...
var numOfTabs = ( match ) ? match[ 0 ].length : 0;
```

Another possibility is to use a loop and charAt:

```
//This string has 3 tabs and 2 spaces: "<tab><tab><space>something<space><tab>"
var str = "      something  ";

var numOfTabs = 0;
var start = 0;

//Loop and count number of tabs at beg
while ( str.charAt( start++ ) == "\t" ) numOfTabs++;
```

Comment: You are using different variable names in the first example, as well as having a typo with `) )`.

Comment: sorry, I just wrote it in the textarea of stackoverflow. I'll fix.

Comment: Also, now, in ES6, you may use a regex like: `'\t\tabc'.match(/\t/gy) || '').length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *general* if you can calculate the data by simply iterating through the string and doing a character check at every index, this will be faster than a regex/regular expression which must build up a more complex searching engine.  I encourage you to profile this but I think you'll find the straight search is faster.

Note: Your search should use `===` instead of `==` here as you don't need to introduce conversions in the equality check.

```
function numberOfTabs(text) {
  var count = 0;
  var index = 0;
  while (text.charAt(index++) === "\t") {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Why would an empty string or all tabs give an error? `charAt()` still returns a value comparable to `"\t"`.

Comment: @patrick  it won't. I'm still thinking in strict code which would crap out on the index out of bounds vs. javascript which will just return undefined.  Will update

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the check for text.length is not needed as javascript still returns a comparable instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) (such as [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) or one of the [many available backend profilers](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/profiler)) to create and run benchmarks on your target systems (the browsers and/or interpreters you plan to support for your software).

It's useful to reason about which solution will perform best based on your expected data and target system(s); however, you may sometimes be surprised by which solution actually performs fastest, especially with regard to big-oh analysis and typical data sets.

In your specific case, iterating over characters in the string will likely be faster than regular expression operations.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory - and I created another - http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-indexof-in-loop

Comment: Sean, thanks for doing that! The problem with those tests is they do them in sequence and the more you run a loop in a browser, the slower the next loop will be as the browser is using ram and cpu. I've found that if you run code A first and then code B, then switch them and try the test again, you'll get the first one almost always being faster.

Comment: maerics, no idea. I gave it an upvote. It's showing a +1 and an orange on the top triangle for me.

Comment: @maerics - are you reviewing your own posts?! Why are you linking to jsPerf. It has nothing to do with the question and is not an answer

Comment: @checklist: because OP was asking about how to identify the fastest of the solutions he presented and my answer is "use a profiler for your target systems".

Comment: although the question uses the word "what's" the writer intent is to know how to do X in the fastest way. It is not about which tool to use to benchmark.

Comment: @checklist I've reworded my answer to clarify that the advice is to "use a profiler" and moved the specific suggestion of jsperf (or other) to a parenthetical expression.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner (if you find smallest is best):

```
"\t\tsomething".split(/[^\t]/)[0].length;
```

i.e. splitting by all non-tab characters, then fetching the first element and obtaining its length.

Comment: The OP specifically said they were interested in "fastest", not "smallest".  regex and split will probably not be involved in a fastest solution.

Comment: Agree with jfriend00, split is a slow function. But appreciate the help! :)